# Como copiar uma tabela do excel para um indicador do word

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, microsoft-word

Estou com dificuldade em copiar uma tabela para um indicador num documento word.

A ideia seria substituir um indicador "TABELA" no word pela tabela "Tabela1" do Excel, tentei utilizar a seguinte forma:

```
Set tabela = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Planilha1").Range

Set docword = wordapp.Documents.Open(...)

docword.Bookmarks("Tabela").Range.Text = tabela
```

Porém, dessa forma, o que está acontecendo é que o indicador "TABELA" no word está sendo substituído pela palavra "Planilha1", ao invés de a tabela toda ser copiada no seu lugar...

Answer (score -1):

Salve, colega! Eu consegui fazer copiando e colando:

```
Set tabela = ActiveSheet.UsedRange 'Ou qualquer outra range
Set docWord = '...

tabela.Copy
docWord.Bookmarks("Tabela").Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False
```

A documentação de `Range.PasteExcelTable` pode ser encontrada [aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.pasteexceltable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.pasteexceltable)